# Twig Templete not found - Sure its right path

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

Please bear in mind i am fairly new to mac and symfony in general so if i am missing anything basic thats why.

so first of all this is what my folder structure looks like-

```
/src
    /TeamRock
       /Fortress
       /Platform
       /Sites ---> the bundles are stored in "Sites"
         /ExampleBundle
         /CalvinBundle <-bundle where i am working->
            /Controller
               /WelcomeController.php
            /Resources
               /config
               /views
                  /CalvinIndex
                      /index.html.twig
            /DependencyInjection
```

And here is my Controller class

```
<?php

namespace TeamRock\Sites\CalvinBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
/**
* Class Welcome
* @package TeamRock\CalvinBundle\Controller
* @Route("/calvin")
*/
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/index", name="calvin_test_index")
 */
public function indexAction (){
    return $this ->      render('TeamRockSitesCalvinBundle:CalvinIndex:index.html.twig');
}

}
```

The Twig file is just a few basic word but the issue is my render? im sure it is, i have looked up the documentation for "path to bundles ect and this makes sence so i am not sure where i am going wrong

any questions or other code needed just comment! thanks for any help in advance!

Calvin!

Comment: Have you tried  with  `return $this ->      render('TeamRockCalvinBundle:CalvinIndex:index.html.twig');
` ?

Comment: Yeah I had that originally then thought because i didn't have  "Sites" in the path that thats why it wasn't working. not sure still keep getting the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

Biggest faceplam ever, it was my views folder, i had named "view" overlooked it so many times... cheers anyways for the help

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
return $this->render(
    'TeamRock\Sites\CalvinBundle\Resources\views\CalvinIndex\index.html.twig'
);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying tried it man still not taking it its hitting my with this:-        Unable to find template       "TeamRock\Sites\CalvinBundle\Resources\views\CalvinIndex\index.html.twig".